# How do I remove white space at the top of my inserted matlab code?

Tags: spacing, matlab

**I've Solved This Question: use \vspace{-1cm}**

I'm using this package:

```
\usepackage[autolinebreaks]{mcode}
```

I want to put a subtitle for my Matlab code and then have it follow on immediately after with no white space, unlike what I currently have. Thanks

[image: Image of current output]
Update to answer one of the comments:

MATLAB Code:

```
%coding fomula: h/3(f0+4f1+2f2+4f3+.....+2f(n-2)+4f(n-1)+fn) i.e. Simpson's
%Rule to calculate integral of ln(x)/x between [1,8]
clear
clc
%setting limits 
p=1,q=8; 
%variable changed for clarity in function later
x=p;
%number of points
n=3000;
```

LATEX Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[autolinebreaks]{mcode}

\begin{document}

\underline{{\large\textit{Simpson:}}}
\lstinputlisting{q2_part1_edit.m}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I solved the problem: I did \vspace{-1 cm}

Comment: You want my entire latex code?

Comment: I have included my packages if that's what you meant

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean but i've just done the same thing in a much simpler document to show you the problem and all the latex code, in the picture above

Comment: Ah, okay. Is that okay what I've done now? I don't think i've done it quite in the same way as you asked, but i guess you can just copy and paste it in?

Comment: Because I don't know how to upload a matlab file :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your `\vspace{-1cm}` works it is not a very nice solution to first add a space and then remove it afterwards. The mcode package introduces a `1.5\baslineskip` space above every listings. So what you should do is change this length to whatever you like. In my example it is `0.5\baselineskip`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[autolinebreaks]{mcode}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.m}   
%coding fomula: h/3(f0+4f1+2f2+4f3+.....+2f(n-2)+4f(n-1)+fn) i.e. Simpson's
%Rule to calculate integral of ln(x)/x between [1,8]
clear
clc
%setting limits 
p=1,q=8; 
%variable changed for clarity in function later
x=p;
%number of points
n=3000;
\end{filecontents*}

\lstset{aboveskip={0.5\baselineskip}} % <-- CHANGE SPACE HERE

\begin{document}

\underline{{\large\textit{Simpson:}}}
\lstinputlisting{\jobname.m}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, `mcode` sets `aboveskip=1.5\baselineskip` which is undobtedly too much. However, the setting can also be local, with `\lstinputlisting[aboveskip=<dimen>]{file}`